# Cakephp not able to save associated model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I've a model `CloudApp` which has HABTM relationship with `Policy` model e.g:

```
class CloudApp extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'name';        
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Policy' => array(
            'className' => 'Policy',
            'joinTable' => 'cloudapp_policies',
            'foreignKey' => 'cloud_app_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'policy_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        )
    );

}
```

`Policy` model looks like this-

```
class Policy extends AppModel {
        public $belongsTo = 'CloudApp'; 
}
```

When I use scaffolding, everything works fine- I am able to multi-select policies for CloudApp that I am saving.

But when I try to manually save data, associated data in Policy model is not getting saved.

Here is my `add` controller-

public function add() {
    $this->loadModel('Policy');
    $this->set('policies', $this->Policy->find('list', array(
                'fields' => array('Policy.name')
    )));

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    pr($this->request->data);
    $this->CloudApp->saveAll($this->request->data);        }
```

}

add.ctp looks like this-

```
echo $this->Form->create('CloudApp');
?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add Application'); ?></legend>
    <?php    
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->input('policies', array(
        'multiple' => true
    ));    

    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Output of  `pr($this->request->data);` is-

```
Array
(
    [CloudApp] => Array
        (
            [name] => 123
            [policies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 18
                    [1] => 19
                    [2] => 20
                )

        )

)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `CloudApp` _HasAndBelongsToMany_ `Policy` then `Policy` should be in the same relationship with `CloudApp` and not _BelongsTo_. For the data to be passed to saveAll in caso of HABTM relationship look at the manual [http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm]

Comment: http://patisserie.keensoftware.com/en/pages/how-to-save-habtm-data-in-cakephp